# Dispute about drafting a paper

Tags: publications

Few years ago I completed a human trial (set up, data collection and analysis). My colleague and I drafted the paper however my line manager never provided any comments. Although I had to move on to another job, there were back and forth email exchanges until 2018 regarding paper updates. However, in 2018 he never sent me his comments. Now I asked him to continue and finalise the paper however he said that another researcher will draft it although this researcher was not involved in the study and has nothing to do with it. I tried to set up a meeting with them but he really pushes me out as if he doesn’t want me involved at all. What should I do? And what can I do if he adds other people to authorship? Thank you

Comment: Why didn't you submit in 2018? Why did you need your manager's comments? Your manager probably feels like 'if you didn't finish it 3 years ago, why would you finish it now'?

Comment: You probably cannot stop him from adding additional authors, but you could mention that you would like to make sure to contribute enough to  remain first author as originally planned (this way, you make clear that you expect to be at least coauthor, without putting that ever into question ;-)